# Default custom fields in Asana?

Tags: asana

What are the custom fields that "ship" with Asana?

For example, if I go to Add Fields > Add Existing Field to Project, I see a list with a bunch of fields I can choose from.

Some of those are custom ones created by the team:

> [image]

While others are official fields automatically created by Asana (i.e. defaults):

> [image]
>
> [image]

Since fields seem to be global to an organization, it makes it really hard to find all of the default fields Asana has. I need to guess at what field Asana might have (e.g. "Priority"), type it in, then scroll the list and look for the Asana logo near it.

I could easily miss a ton of these (e.g. if I didn't happen to try typing "Office" I could have easily not known that this was a default custom field).

The reason I want to know which are the defaults is because fields are global to an organization, it could easily balloon to thousands of different fields that are very closely related (e.g. `Priority.` and `Priority Rank` in the screenshots above). I'm hoping most people would converge on these default fields (even if they aren't exactly the same) and prevent the need for all these duplicates.

---

Since anyone can create a personal Asana account for free, I tried creating a new account and seeing what appears in the custom fields list for a brand new organization, however, custom fields are a [Premium feature](https://asana.com/pricing).

Also, I can't scroll the entire list because there are thousands of fields already defined by the organization. The best I can do is type "a", but even then it limits the results to only about 40 when scrolling the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to find the list, the best I could do is type each letter "a" then "b" etc. and scroll the list, looking for the Asana logo on each one. This is not accurate because the list returned is limited to about 40 entries, so there are definitely more than what is in this list below:

```
A/V Requirements
Allotted Time
Approval Stage
Approved?
Added by
Board Committee
Content Channel
Content Stage
Content Type
Creation Stage
Creative Channel
Department
External Steps Needed
Estimated Work
Favorite Idea
Feedback Type
Hiring Status
Idea Status
Interview Stage
Meeting Minutes
Meeting Needed
Minutes
Number of user reports
Office Location
Participants Needed
Pipeline Stage
Post Format
Priority Rank
Product Stage
Project size
Project Status (Request Received, Action Required, In Progress, Completed, Backlog)
Point of Contact
Room Name
Referral
Request Type
Size
Social Channels
System Setup
Task Progress (Not Started, In Progress, Waiting, Deferred, Done)
```

Additionally, I searched for some words that may uncover others: `project, task, stage, status, product, type, time, by, size, report, number, estimate, content, channel`